# SplitViewController app crashes when loading webview

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite, uiwebview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an app that uses a splitViewController that loads a html file from a sqlite database. I have an iphone app that does the same thing. It loads a tableview with the database contents and then pushes a webview onto the stack when user touches a cell. All works great with the iPhone app, but not in the iPad with the splitViewController. Everything works except when loading the webview.

Here is the concerned code in the header file:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @class LIDetailViewController;

  @interface LIMasterViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>{

  @property (strong, nonatomic) LIDetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

And in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;
```

Here is the code that it is crashing on:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if (!_detailViewController) {
        _detailViewController = [[LIDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LIDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController  animated:YES];
}


NSString *sqlData = [animal  description];
NSString *htmlHead = @"<head><link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='default.css'><head/><body><div class='content'>";
NSString *htmlBody = [sqlData stringByAppendingString:@"</div>"];   
NSString *html = [htmlHead stringByAppendingString:htmlBody];
[_detailViewController.animalDescripton loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

It is crashing on the line that says:

```
[_detailViewController.animalDescripton loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

This is the error in the debugger:  "[UINavigationController animalDescripton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x685fa70"

If anyone can help me with this it would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whenever I've used a `UIWebView`, I pass in `baseURL:nil`. Is there a reason you're passing in your `mainBundle`? You're supplying the entirety of the HTML in the NSString, right?

Comment: That is a good point that seems to work great. that was a chunk of code I borrowed from someone else... Thanks for the tip. That doesn't seem to solve the problem but it is good anyway. Have any idea why I would be getting a crash on that code??

Comment: What error do you get? Also, I'm assuming that `animalDescription` **is**, in fact, a `UIWebView`, right? (Cover all the bases...)

Comment: This is the error in the debugger. Yes, animalDescription is a UIWebview. [UINavigationController animalDescripton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x685fa70

Comment: For some reason, the compiler doesn't know that `_detailViewController` isn't just a plain UINavigationController. How do you instantiate it for the iPad? You've only shown iPhone code so far...

Comment: I added the code that I used to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently never set `self.detailViewController` when on the iPad, so it seems to default to a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: This was part of the problem. The other part was that I had failed to properly set up the app delegate. Thanks for the help.